# Socket.io disconnect client by id

Tags: node.js, socket.io, disconnect

I'm new to nodejs and trying to write a chat room as so many people have.
The chat consists of multiple rooms and clients. Commands such as `/nick` `/join` `/help` `/ls users` `/ls rooms` work as you would expect although I'm having trouble with getting a `/kick` command to work.

I'm just not sure how you disconnect a client by id, so far `/kick client` is able to present the respective clients socket.id although I'm stuck for the code to kick via socket.id.

Code so far:

Disconnect client who sent `/kick`: `socket.disconnect();`

**Delete** client from arg `/kick client`: `delete io.sockets.sockets[client];`

Deleting the client doesn't disconnect them though, they can still receive data just not send it.

### Solved

CuriousGuy's 0.9 worked flawlessly, for those interested - here is the code I'm using.

Server side:

```
handleClientKick(socket);

...

function handleClientKick(socket) {
  socket.on('kick', function(client) {
    if (typeof io.sockets.sockets[client] != 'undefined') {
      socket.emit('message', {text: nickNames[socket.id] + ' kicked: ' + nickNames[client]});
      io.sockets.sockets[client].disconnect();
    } else {
      socket.emit('message', {text: 'User: ' + name + ' does not exist.'});
    }
  });
}
```

Client side:

```
kickClient = function(client) {
  this.socket.emit('kick', client);
};
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following code works with Socket.IO 1.0, however I'm not sure that this is the best solution:

```
if (io.sockets.connected[socket.id]) {
    io.sockets.connected[socket.id].disconnect();
}
```

**Update:**

With Socket.IO 0.9 the code would be slightly different:

```
if (io.sockets.sockets[socket.id]) {
    io.sockets.sockets[socket.id].disconnect();
}
```

Comment: hmm, I get an undefined when I run `console.log(io.sockets.connected[socket.id])` any idea?

Comment: It means that either this socket is disconnected already, or `socket.id` value is invalid. What do you get if you run `console.log(socket.id);`?

Comment: I tested my solution with Socket.IO 1.0

Comment: `socket.id` works as expected returning `BGGkTQOOBJTcO2YukQLl` etc.. - just checked and I'm using 0.9.16, I'll try with 1.0

Comment: running into all sorts of other errors trying my pre-1.0 code running on 1.0 (sort of expected that). I find it strange how hard it is for me to disconnect a client by the clients `socket.id` yet so simple in general to setup sockets.io.

Comment: Maybe you will find [this article](http://socket.io/docs/migrating-from-0-9/) useful.

Comment: BTW, I've edited my answer adding a solution for 0.9 that seems to work for me

Comment: the 0.9 code worked perfectly, so simple. Thank you for the article, really appreciate the help!

Comment: How to can I reconnect, without refresh browser?  I tried execute io() by client side, but is not work

Comment: tested on current socket.io (1.3.something? anyway you can see a date of my msg) io.sockets.connected is still in place, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

This is an old question but if anyone wonders for newer versions;

In **Socket.IO v4.X** `io.sockets.connected[socket.id]` or `io.sockets.sockets[socket.id]` is not working.

So we need to do like this;

```
io.sockets.sockets.forEach((socket) => {
    // If given socket id is exist in list of all sockets, kill it
    if(socket.id === givenSocketID)
        socket.disconnect(true);
});
```

Comment: `io.sockets.sockets.get(socketId)` worked for me. V4.7.2

Answer (score 4):

Alternate solution In **Socket.IO v4.X**

**For all sockets**

```
const sockets = await io.fetchSockets();
```

**For particular socket**

```
const sockets = await io.in(theSocketId).fetchSockets();
```

**Iterate sockets**

```
for (const socket of sockets) {
     console.log("socket id",socket.id);
     socket.disconnect(true);
}
```

[Reference link](https://socket.io/docs/v4/migrating-from-3-x-to-4-0/)

Comment: Would `io.in(theSocketId).fetchSockets` ever return multiple sockets?

Comment: No it will return one only, loop can be removed

Answer (score 4):

Here's another option for Socket.IO v4 that doesn't require async syntax:

```
io.sockets.sockets.get(socket.id)
```

Someone can correct this if it's wrong, but I think each socket has a unique ID, so there should be no need for iterating.

Comment: it didn't worked for me, it returns undefined

Comment: Nice and clean. Worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Server:

```
var users = {};
socket.on("identify", (username, id) => {
  eval("users." + username + " = " + '"' + socket.id + '"')
});
socket.on("getId", (username) => {
  console.log(eval("users." + username))
});
socket.on("kick", (username) => {
  io.sockets.sockets.forEach((socket) => {
    if(socket.id === eval("users." + username))
        socket.disconnect(true);
});
})
```

Client:

```
const username = prompt("What Is Your Name?")
socket.emit("identify", username)
```

Description:
When the client enters the web page they get asked what their name is then it sends the name to the server then the server gets the id of the client and stores the name in the opject 'Users' and gives it a value of the id 'users.name = the user's socket.ID' then when you write in the console on the client side 'socket.emit("kick", username of the user)' it disconnects that user from the socket so they can't chat anymore until they reload so it pretty much kicks them from the chat.