# Socket.IO 4.0.1: Get socket by id

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I used

```
const my_socket = io.sockets.connected['YnwlYH-gCKT2K9jEAAAu'];
```

a lot.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24464450/1707015

Is it broken in 3.X and 4.0.1?

```
$ npm list socket.io
socket.io@4.0.1

$ npm list socket.io-client
socket.io-client@4.0.1
```

```
# Object.keys(io.sockets):
_events,_eventsCount,_maxListeners,sockets,_fns,_ids,server,name,adapter

# io.sockets.connected:
undefined

# io.sockets.connected['YnwlYH-gCKT2K9jEAAAu']:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'YnwlYH-gCKT2K9jEAAAu' of undefined
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/path:row:char)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:86:5)
```

I can get it run with version 2 (instead of 3 or 4):

```
$ npm install --quiet --save-dev socket.io@2.X socket.io-client@2.X
```

Yes, this is literally an `X` - for the newest sub version.

Do you have any refactoring instructions?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This question and answer is probably a (newer/better) duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/66835961/1707015. Sorry, I only saw it now. Credits to Sanjay Nishad.

---

```
const my_socket = io.sockets.sockets.get('YnwlYH-gCKT2K9jEAAAu');
```

Comment: For context, this is documented here: https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-api/#namespacesockets
Where it says that `namespace.sockets` is of type `Map<SocketId, Socket>`
So to explain the above:
`io.sockets` is the default namespace 
`defeaultNamespace.sockets` is a Map
where a Map has a method called `get()` that happens to return an object of type `Socket`

Comment: How does this work with adapter? Does `io.sockets.sockets` contains all sockets from across the adapter, e.g. Redis?

Comment: This solution is not working for redis adapter. It is working fine when we run in a single node. But when it comes to multi nodes with redis adapter, it is not working. Any solution that works for redis adapter?

Comment: @Prakash did you find a solution? As per the [docs](https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-api/#namespacesockets), would something like this work: `const socket = io.of("/").sockets.get('<socket_id>') `

Comment: @MikeK Yes, posted the solution.

Answer (score 0):

For any adapter, you can use fetchSockets() function to get the socket connection by socketId.

```
const socketList = await io.in(socketId).fetchSockets();
```

Instead of socketId, you can use socketRoom as well.

Refer [here](https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-instance/#fetchsockets) for the documentation.

Answer (score -1):

"socket.io": "^4.1.3"

```
nsp.sockets.get(socketid).join(roomId)
nsp.to(roomId).emit("message",{message : "something"})
```

it worked for me

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.